# Multiple counts in one table output should be one table

Tags: mysql

I want to create the following mysql query to put multiple count run on same table and output should be in one table only using as `name`.

```
select 
    count(select count(TXN)  
          from sale1 
          where date(SALEDATE) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
         ) as c1,
    count(select count(TXN) 
          from sale1 
          where RESPONSE='Y' 
            AND date(SALEDATE) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
         ) as c2 
FROM sale1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, remove the `(` and `)` from the parent query, do away with the outer `FROM` and the extra `count`'s. That is,

`SELECT
   (SELECT count(TXN) 
        FROM sale1 
        WHERE DATE(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
   ) AS c1,
   (SELECT count(TXN) 
        FROM sale1 
        WHERE RESPONSE='Y' 
        AND DATE(SALEDATE)=DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
   ) AS c2;`

Note count of count i.e. `count(count(*))` will normally give you 1.